# How to use variables with a dash in the name in Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to render a map that has keys containing minus signs (e.g. first-name), e.g.:

```
<head><title>Data - ${first-name} </title>
```

When I render it with FreeMarker, it complains and throws an exception. When I remove the '-' from the variable name, it works OK.

Is there any way to escape these variables in the Groovy template text?

The reason I'm doing it this way is to render a JSON blob from a 3rd party API, where I have no control over the variable-names.

Answer (score 4):

Just checked the [Freemarker manual](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html). In chapter "Retrieving variables" you have the following statement:

> For example, to read the variable whose name is "data-id", the
>   expression is data\-id, as data-id would be interpreted as "data minus
>   id". (Note that these escapes only work in identifiers, not in string
>   literals.)

These type of expressions work fine in Freemarker 2.3.23 (just tested to verify the documentation):

```
<#if test\-dash??>
    ${test\-dash}
</#if>
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked :) I just had to upgrade to 2.3.23. Thanks!

Comment: @JustinLawler If you upgrade anyway, why not to the latest 2.3.x version?

Answer (score 1):

Only if you are using freemarker version from 2.3.22 or above. See [freemarker variable syntax](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html):

> In this kind of expression, the variable name can only contain letters (including non-Latin letters), digits (including non-Latin digits), underline (_), dollar ($), at sign (@). Furthermore, the first character can't be a ASCII digit (0-9). Starting from FreeMarker 2.3.22, the variable name can also contain minus (-), dot (.), and colon (:) at any position, but these must be escaped with a preceding backslash (\), or else they would be interpreted as operators.